# How can I get the escape key to work in Mac OS X (10.7) Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I’ve used <kbd>esc</kbd> to get out of `vi`’s insert mode for 40 years. I am not going to relearn that keystroke as <kbd>ctl</kbd>-<kbd>esc</kbd>, period.

Even if I were to do that, then I’d be typing <kbd>ctl</kbd>-<kbd>esc</kbd> on other platforms where it would not work because I have to type <kbd>esc</kbd> alone.

If there is a way to fix in in System Preferences, I cannot find it. If there is not, then it is completely 100% brain-dead wrong. I hope that’s not the case.

Comment: They're trying to force you to move to emacs. *runs*

Comment: That would be nice, but I am also having trouble getting the X11 flavor of emacs to work.  Yes, the character flavor works fine, but using the mouse to cut and paste is a requirement nowadays.  That not withstanding, my virtual machines emulate systems too small for everything.  "vi" is the only editor.  Must...use...vi.  :(  - Bruce (emacs user since 1984)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:  Speech Recognition takes the escape key by itself and does not make it clear that it has done so.  I had apparently activated it without realizing it and it was non-obvious that it was the source of the problem.  The solution is to either deactivate it or select a less obtrusive "mic on" key sequence.

Comment: Consider creating a question about why the hotkey was in use by Speech recognition when you didn't have a big-ass *Speech* item floating above all other windows with the label `Esc` in it and that flickered and changed color whenever you pressed the hotkey. And could you please remove the pointless rant in your question?

Comment: I just want to bump this up, because both this problem and this solution are still relevant 12 years later.  I was having this problem and I have no idea how long it would have taken to diagnose if I hadn't found this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>esc</kbd> for exiting vi's insert mode works fine in both `Terminal.app` and `iTerm2.app` even in full-screen mode. Perhaps you have modified your profile or something remapping the <kbd>esc</kbd> key to something else.

Comment: If I did, it wasn't intentional.  Also, I've meandered through every setting I can locate under System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts.  I do not see a circumflex by itself.  They all appear attached to another character, pointedly not including Control-escape (I guess that would be, "^Escape", but I don't see escape anywhere).

I am using a terminal program named, "Terminal", by the way.

Comment: What DOES happen when you press esc in Terminal?

Comment: No response at all.  It is like not pressing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically due to the “Speakable Item Enable” as you set <kbd>esc</kbd> key to listen to your voice so please disable it for <kbd>esc</kbd> key proper functioning.